# numerating chapters in book- format

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, chapters

I would like to have the following formatting in the table of contents:

```
1. Chapter 1
1.1 Section 1
1.2 Section 2
```

And also I want to use `\chapter` but instead of appearing.

```
Chapter 1

Chapter 1
```

I want

```
1. Chapter 1.
```

I have tried different combinations (using the `titlesec` package without success).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here's one possibility. [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) was used to change the format for chapter headings and [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) to add the period after the unit number in the ToC:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{\Huge}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{Test section one one}
\section{Test section one two}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC:

[image]

An image of the new chapter heading format:

[image]